# Snowpack: Is it possible to mount directories that are within a parent directory?

Tags: configuration, mount, snowpack

**Pre-empt:** I am *VERY* new to Snowpack.

**Issue:**
I am attempting to mount `/public` and `/src` directories which are within a parent directory [See below]. I know this (essentially) defies convention, but I have an unusual use case.

**Folder structure**

> - root
>
>   - module
>
>     - snowpack.config.js
>     - ...
>   - src
>
>     - main.js
>     - ...
>   - public
>
>     - index.html
>     - ...

**Why an issue:**
I must refer to mounted directories with base `/` (e.g. `/src`), and attempts with relative directories return this error: `[15:12:04] [snowpack] mount[C:\Users\User\root\module]: Value "C:\Users\User\root\src" must be a URL path, and start with a "/"`. This also prevents relative paths.

I have attempted to change root and workspaceRoot to the directory of interest (in this case `C:\Users\User\root`) without avail. How, if possible, can I make this work?

**snowpack.config.js**

```
/** @type {import("snowpack").SnowpackUserConfig } */
module.exports = {
  mount:{
    public: "../public",
    src: "../src",
  },
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those with this issue, the syntax for `mount` within `snowpack.config.js` isn't 100% clear on the docs. See the example below. Mount here provides reference to a relative or absolute path, and what path it signifies for snowpack. In this case, the relative path `../` signifies the root (`/`).

```
mount: {
  '../': '/',
},
```